# Closing a Modal (via delegate) from a different View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I'm hoping that i'm simply overlooking something simple.  But here the scenario.

I have a root vc that opens a modal view LoginScreen.  In that view class I've set up a protocol (ViewControllerDelegate) synthesized, and once a user logs in via the modal, the parent VC closes the modal and all is well.

In LoginScreen.m to close the modal all I have to use is this code:

```
[self.delegate loginConfirmed:self];
```

That works perfectly.  However, I have another view that gets pushed is login is confirmed.  Still as a modal of course.  Call it LoginScreen2.

I can't figure out how to get the Modal to close from LoginScreen2 and get back tot he root VC.  I've tried a bunch of different variations like this, but no luck.

```
[((LoginScreen *)self.parentViewController).delegate loginConfirmed:((LoginScreen *)self)];
```

I've been searching and messing around for a couple hours, with no luck.  Again I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple and just not seeing it.   If anyone has any ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: I didn't catch the problem right, you have a second modal view, presented after the LoginScreen? And you can't get it dismissed?

Comment: Hey @LuisEspinoza - Thanks for checking in on this.  I was overcomplicating things for myself tonight.  Danh solution below explained it perfectly.  But I appreciate you're willingness to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure who is presenting the second view controller, but one thing that might help you is to know that a modally presented  view controller can dismiss itself:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The root view controller can check the user state when it appears, and `presentModalViewController:Login1`.  Login1 changes the user sign-in state, and dismisses itself.  Root sees different user state (when it's about to reappear via the `viewWillAppear:` method) and presents modal on `Login2`.  No delegation needed.

Comment: Wow, looks like I just spent a bunch of time overcomplicating this for myself!  Thank you very much for the explanation and ideas.  Works like a charm and is much less complicated!  Thanks, danh